# Cannot install or run Ubuntu from USB flash drive

Tags: installation, live-environment

I've already tried a lot of different variations of install but still wasn't able to do this. I'm talking about 12.04 x64 version, but I've also tried 13.04 which doesn't work either.

I'm quite sure that it's hardware problem, so I'll describe my PC properties:

- Motherboard: ASRock FM2A85X Extreme4-M;
- Processor: AMD A8 5600K Quad-Core Processor;
- Videocard: AMD Radeon HD 6600;
- 4 GB RAM.

The screen turns off after I try to run or install (but if I set `nomodeset` with X installation it will proceed a little bit, but then just freeze nonetheless).

I also tried to install Ubuntu with Windows 7 installer, but Ubuntu won't work this way.

The flash drive works fine, because on other machine everything installed normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem  when I used the "start up disk creator" that came with ubuntu to create the live USB and strangely enough it was working fine on other devices so I also thought it was a hardware problem.

this was solved by either using  the latest version of [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) in Linux or [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) in windows

Comment: I'd also recommend pendrivelinux.com. Had the same issue earlier.